# Separating power from data micro USB to HDMI

Tags: power-supply, usb, adapter, hdmi, monitor

I have a camera which both draws power and sends its data through a battery pack to a custom monitor. The monitor also draws power as well as receives the camera data through the battery pack. (Both the camera and the monitor connect to the Battery pack with Micro USB) I intended to use a monitor which uses its own power supply so I used a Micro USB to HDMI converter meant for phones(MHL). However it didn't work, the adapter smelled burnt and the HDMI port on the monitor no longer worked however the HDMI cable itself still works. I figured it must be because the battery pack outputs both the camera data as well as power, the power must have burnt out everything. Is it possible to separate the power output from the data output and to convert it from Micro USB to HDMI without burning out the ports?
Additionally I opened the monitor that came with the battery and camera and the Micro USB Wire connected to a circuit board with a smaller red, black, and green wire. The battery pack consists of two 18650 rechargeable batteries(3.7 Volts, 2500mah). [image]

Answer (score 2):

The AMT630A chip inside the monitor is a chip for receiving analog composite video and conveting it to digital to drive the TFT panel.

There is no digital video that is compatible with MHL or HDMI.

You can of course make a cable that only provides the analog composite for connecting it to an older TV directly or using a converter box to make it HDMI.

So the manufacturer simply used a standard connector for non-standard purposes, and thus using existing cables it is possible to damage equipment - therefore standard connectors should never be used for non-standard purposes. The HDMI input of the monitor is now damaged.

Modifying and using equipment for purposes they are not meant for needs awful lot of research whether it can be modified or used for other purposes to prevent damage.